# How do I get automatic blink on opening parenthesis when I insert closing parenthesis in emacs24?

Tags: emacs

How do i get emacs24 to blink on opening parenthesis when I insert closing parenthesis?

I tried show-paren-mode, it shows opening parenthesis when i place
cursor on closing parenthesis. But, I'm looking for automatic blink of
highlight on opening paren when i insert close paren.

I've below knobs currently.

```
(setq show-paren-delay 0)
(show-paren-mode t)
(setq blink-matching-paren t)
```

Comment: I have the same settings (`blink-matching-paren` is `t` by default) and get exactly what you are describing.

Comment: Hmm. Is it possible to you to share your .email settings ?.

Comment: https://github.com/bo0ts/.emacs

Comment: I had evil (vim) extension enabled which caused blink to be stopped. Currently I've removed evil. I need if someone from my team wants to browse code in my system while debugging and they are vim users.

Comment: By `disable` you mean remove the require or just do `(evil-mode 0)`? The first shouldn't be the case. You should be able to enable evil on demand for your co-workers by executing `M-x evil-mode` in a buffer to turn it off/on.

Comment: You are right. I tried your suggestion to keep evil-mode 0 and that worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to evil package. I had to disable it to get automatic blink working.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work for you if the opening and closing parens are close by?

If it does not work only when they are far apart then increase the value of option `blink-matching-paren-distance`.  (I use a value of 256000.)

Other than that, narrow down your init file -- we should not do that for you.  It is simple to do: bisect it by commenting out half (I use `M-x comment-region` -- and with a plain `C-u` it uncomments).  Then comment out 3/4, then 7/8, then 15/16,... until you can say exactly what the culprit code is.

Comment: Unrelated: use `comment-dwim` bound to `M-;`. It figures out what do for you (comment/uncomment/region/line).

Comment: @pmr: I disagree, but it is a question of personal preference. `comment-dwim` is no substitute for `comment-region`. The latter gives you more options wrt the prefix arg, the comment prefix etc. I use `comment-dwim` (`M-;`) pretty much only for its `comment-indent` behavior, i.e., add/indent an end-of-line comment.  Which was done just as well by `comment-indent` aka `indent-for-comment` (previously `M-;`) before `comment-dwim` was dreamed up.